# Shared dataset appears for selection even after deleting from report server report builder3.0

Tags: reporting-services

I created a Shared Dataset in report builder 3.0 a week ago and stored in my "My Reports" folder on report server.I removed it the other day; however, when I go to create a new Dataset today...it's still listed as an option.  When you attempt to select it from the list you receive an error message that it's no longer available. Below is the error which I am getting :

"The shared dataset cannot be loaded from the server".

Please help if anyone has faced a similar issue and know the reason for it. Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: I'm guessing the reason is that you deleted it but the program was holding a cache of existing reports hence why you had the option. I don't think that it's anything to worry about.

Comment: But I closed my report builder and my report manager too ... again after a week when i opened my report manager and then my report builder ..... went ahead creating a new dataset ... it showed me that deleted shared dataset ??

Comment: what happens is if i create more shared datasets and delete them the list is growing in Add Dataset wizard since all of them appears even after deleting.

Answer (score 2):

Ren is more or less correct, Report Builder is caching a list of items you've recently used.  It does not bother to check if the items it's caching actually exist or not, which is why you're getting the error you do when you try to use one.

To clear the list, click the big icon in the top left (or alt + F), then click the Options button at the bottom of the dialog that appears.

In the options window you can clear your recent item lists, along with change some of the rules for how those are kept.

I don't believe there's any way to make Report Builder *automatically* remove broken/missing references

Comment: Hi Ren, I am facing the same problem in visual studio 2010 and 2012, I can see the deleted shared datasets in the same project as well as other projects, I asked it as a separate [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27954066/shared-dataset-appears-for-selection-even-after-deleting-from-project-in-visual) but not sure why people are negative scoring it, could you please suggest me an answer